# converting string to const wchar_t* but as the way L"string" does

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to use `L""` with a variable `x` but any method I use expands into `Lx` so compiler can't understand it and gives me undefined error. I couldn't find an answer to it

So I tried to casting `string` into a `wchar_t*` by using some functions that I found like this one:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std ;

wstring widen( const string& str )
{
    wostringstream wstm ;
    const ctype<wchar_t>& ctfacet = use_facet<ctype<wchar_t>>(wstm.getloc()) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<str.size() ; ++i ) 
              wstm << ctfacet.widen( str[i] ) ;
    return wstm.str() ;
}

int main()
{
    const char* cstr = "sandbox.exe" ;
    const wchar_t* wcstr = widen(cstr).c_str() ;
    wcout << wcstr << L'\n' ;
  
}
```

But it doesn't give(0000020823B74200) me the same output as `L""`(00007FF72B4DA528)

Apparently `widestring` in the code in the 8th comment (given below) gives the same output as `L"sandbox.exe"` but when converted into `wchar_t*` with `.c_str()` function it becomes something else. I also cannot use `wstring` as a `wchar_t*` unless I cast it with `.c_str()`. I believe my core question is how can I cast `wstring` into `wchar_t*` without using `.c_str()`/changing it.

Code in the 8th comment:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std ;
 
wstring widen( const string& str )
{
    wostringstream wstm ;
    const ctype<wchar_t>& ctfacet = use_facet<ctype<wchar_t>>(wstm.getloc()) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<str.size() ; ++i ) 
              wstm << ctfacet.widen( str[i] ) ;
    return wstm.str() ;
}
 
int main()
{
    const char* cstr = "sandbox.exe" ;
    const std::wstring widestring = widen(cstr);
    const wchar_t* wcstr = widestring.c_str();
    wcout << wcstr << L'\n' ;
 
}
```

Note, when printing or checking if the values are the same it **shows and tells you they are not the same** but **they are the same when using it**.

**The last code works.**

Comment: `wcstr` is a dangling pointer. What it was pointing to immediately goes out of scope and is destroyed. Thus, you have UB.

Comment: In general you can convert `string` to `wstring` simply by constructing it with `string` iterators:  `std::wstring wstr(str.begin(), str.end());`

Comment: [And you see that it is the dangling pointer causing the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/ThT3qb8jM).

Comment: @ChrisMM how can I fix this? I don't know what to do

Comment: Keep a `wstring` variable in your `int main()` that holds the return value from widen()

Comment: @drescherjm tried it but still not gives me what L"" does :/

Comment: [https://ideone.com/DKku5x](https://ideone.com/DKku5x)

Comment: This should also work as long as the std::wstring variable is in scope and is not altered: [https://ideone.com/ljsQtV](https://ideone.com/ljsQtV)

Comment: @drescherjm using the code in the last link you shared, `(widestring==L"sandbox.exe")` is 1 but `(wcstr==L"sandbox.exe")` is 0. Is there a way to cast const wstring to const wchar_t* without using `.c_str()`?